# Accessing values from inner function in pytest fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to access the response from an inner function inside my pytest fixture. I'm not sure if this is a python issue or something unique to how pytest is built. The snippet below is a dumb example, but it demonstrates the issue. I am getting the issue: `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`. Not sure how to solve this and would like some help please.

```
import pytest
import requests


@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    def make_request(url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        return {'code': response.status_code, 'content': response.content}

    response = make_request
    save_for_after_yield = response['content']
    yield response

    # print simulates doing something with the content as part of the clean-up
    print(save_for_after_yield)


def test_making_requests(my_fixture):
    response = my_fixture('http://httpbin.org')
    assert 200 == response
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the inner function is not called until the `yield`, so you cannot save the result before that (and you can't know it, as you don't know the URL parameter). What you can do is saving the variable after it has been set inside the inner function:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    def make_request(url):
        nonlocal response_content  # needed to access the variable in the outer function
        response = requests.get(url)
        response_content = response.content
        return {'code': response.status_code, 'content': response.content}

    response_content = None  # will be set when the fixture is used
    yield make_request
    print(response_content)


def test_making_requests(my_fixture):
    response = my_fixture('http://httpbin.org')
    assert 200 == response['code']
```